# Load Balancing by a server as heavily loaded as google

Tags: networking, scalability, computer-science, load-balancing

Below query shows around 10 IP Addresses belonging to google.com. So, does it mean that there are only 10 servers which act as first stop for any query sent to google? 
Even if these are used only for load balancing, how can they handle millions of requests?

```
host google.com
google.com has address 74.125.228.32
google.com has address 74.125.228.33
google.com has address 74.125.228.34
google.com has address 74.125.228.35
google.com has address 74.125.228.36
google.com has address 74.125.228.37
google.com has address 74.125.228.38
google.com has address 74.125.228.39
google.com has address 74.125.228.40
google.com has address 74.125.228.41
google.com has address 74.125.228.46
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this:

```
bash-3.2$ host google.com
google.com has address 212.188.10.114
google.com has address 212.188.10.88
google.com has address 212.188.10.98
google.com has address 212.188.10.84
google.com has address 212.188.10.93
google.com has address 212.188.10.108
google.com has address 212.188.10.99
google.com has address 212.188.10.123
google.com has address 212.188.10.109
google.com has address 212.188.10.104
google.com has address 212.188.10.119
google.com has address 212.188.10.94
google.com has address 212.188.10.118
google.com has address 212.188.10.89
google.com has address 212.188.10.103
google.com has address 212.188.10.113
```

In other words, users from different countries gets different IPs for 'google.com'. So at least there are much more IP addresses, not just around 10.